# JEE6 @Schedule method

Tags: timer, glassfish

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2.
I have a EJB 3.1 stateless bean that has one method anotatted as:

```
@Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*/5", hour = "5-23", persistent = false)
```

So this method will run at 5:05, 5:10, 5:15, ... which is OK.

What will happen is this method runs for more that 5 minutes? Will at one time run two invocations of this method at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method is inside a `@Singleton` bean only one invocation of the method will run at the same time. However, the container may retry to execute the method on completion which could result in an ongoing execution of the method. A technique to prevent this is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402068/ejb-schedule-wait-until-method-completed).