# Behaviour of concurrent @Schedule methods

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I have a method, annotated as such :

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/1")
public void sampleData () {... Process can be long or short ... }
```

Inside a `@Singleton` EJB. The method is therefore executed by Glassfish every second.

Question :

What happens if the method takes more than 1 second to complete ?

1. Is the invocation cancelled and another method invoked ?
2. Are the calls to the method queued ?
3. Are calls to this method halted whilst the method is still in execution ?
4. Is the same method executed twice concurrently ? (not possible in @Singleton ??)

Would the @Asynchronous annotation modify the default behaviour ?

I want the method to execute every second and no calls made to the @Schedule method until all other instances have completed. How should I configure my class ?

Comment: You may find some relevant information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402068/ejb-schedule-wait-until-method-completed